# Upgrade went horribly wrong: libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found

Tags: grub2, upgrade, filesystem, recovery-mode

File system is mounted readonly, so I boot into recovery mode to run `fsck`, and I get the following message:

```
mountall: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1)
```

... so I'm thinking, it failed to completely download a package.  Well, I'll update the dpkg... except the network is not enabled.

... so I enable the network, to get a message:

```
failed to open lockfile...
```

of course, because it's a readonly filesystem.

How do I get around this catch-22?

This is on an ESXi instance, if that matters.

Comment: What versions of Ubuntu were you upgrading from and to? My guess would be 12.04 to 12.10? In which case you would be better off installing a fresh 14.04.

Comment: For chroot method of fixing see [glibc error: libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125649/reboot-during-update-glibc-error)

Comment: Yeah it'd be really useful if I knew that.  I was doing a `do-release-upgrade` thing and wasn't paying attention.  I don't think I can get the answer now.

Comment: See [Can I look at the upgrade log after a distribution upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130969/can-i-look-at-the-upgrade-log-after-a-distribution-upgrade) and `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bain, I got on the right track by downloading the Live CD iso, and mounting that in my VM, booting up my machine in "trial" mode, and doing the following:

- First, I opened a terminal window with `ctrl-alt-t`
- Changed my login to super user with `sudo su -`
- Installed the LVM management tools with `apt-get install lvm2`
- Started the logical volume manager with `vgchange -a y dev`.  This created two references to my LVM volumes in `/dev/mapper`, with the names of `dev-root` and `dev-swap_1`.  Obviously I was more interested in `/dev/mapper/dev-root`.
- I ran `fsck /dev/mapper/dev-root` and got back a clean FS (? I wasn't expecting that)
- I created a mount point with `mkdir /sda5` (which is probably more confusing than necessary, but I knew the data I wanted was on `sda5`)
- I mounted the FS with `mount /dev/mapper/dev-root /sda5`
- I was then able to traverse my FS and grab the stuff I wanted.
- Then I blew it away and rebuilt the thing.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you do not have a backup. First make a backup. Use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and create an image. You can do more damage if you try to repair things.

Make sure you have enough disk space before proceeding

Now to repair your installation, you have a couple of options:

- boot a Ubuntu live CD and chroot into the root folder of your install, and install the  proper glibc dpkg
- Upgrade install of Ubuntu over the current one.

Or you could just create a new VM. Install Ubuntu, then migrate the applications and configs from the old one. Use a live CD to access the broken VM. Document everything and configure backups.

Comment: How would I do an upgrade install over the current readonly FS?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs When you boot the ISO image and choose "Upgrade" it will mount the filesystem read-write.

Comment: @bain I don't see an upgrade option.  I see Install Ubuntu Server, Multiple server install with MAAS, check disc for defects, Test memory, Boot from first hard disk, and Rescue a broken system.  The "rescue" option seemed most likely but did not seem to offer a "repair file system" option like I was hoping for.