# How to tell if current version was upgraded or a fresh install

Tags: upgrade, version-control

I have a number of installation of ubuntu 16.04.  Some of them were upgraded from a previous version.  Some of them were fresh installs.

Some of my installations have problems that that I don't experience of some of the others.

I'm trying to identify if the problems that I experience are because of problems with the upgrade and if the fresh installs are functioning better.

If the fresh installs are functioning better in every instance, I might perform fresh installs on some of the computers that I experience problem.

Thanks in advance for anyone who knows how to test if the running OS was installed initially as the version running.

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/130969/can-i-look-at-the-upgrade-log-after-a-distribution-upgrade , which mentions the file `/var/log/dist-upgrade`

Comment: @NickWeinberg I was able to use information from the similar question to resolve my issue.  If no one answers, I'll post the specific details that resolved this specific question, so that it can be properly marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 should have no files in directory `/var/log/dist-upgrade`.  So you could test for the existence of main.log there to determine if the installation was a clean install or an upgrade, eg using bash

```
if [ -f /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log ]
then echo upgrade
else echo clean install
fi
```

For more info refer to [DebuggingUpdateManager](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUpdateManager)