# When did I upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: upgrade

It has been several months since I upgraded my Ubuntu version. How can I find the date that I upgraded?

It has been suggested to look in the directory /var/log/dist-upgrade but this directory is empty on my system.

Comment: OP.
It has been suggested to look in the directory /var/log/dist-upgrade but this directory is empty on my system.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but what about ls -l /etc/debian_version

Answer (score 1):

Logs for the upgrade are found in

`/var/log/dist-upgrade`

Mine looks like this

```
-rw------- 1 root root 511516 Jul 19 19:05 apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 428135 Jul 19 19:28 apt.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  636471 Jul 19 19:28 apt-term.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116390 Jul 19 19:28 history.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1125 Jul 19 19:05 lspci.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  64976 Jul 19 19:29 main.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     78 Jul 19 19:29 xorg_fixup.log
```

Presumably I upgraded this VM on July 19th.

Comment: If future users want to use this, they will have to check a different file, yes? I assume if they upgrade to a stable version, it would just be `/var/log/upgrade`?

Comment: I don't think you are correct.  Every upgrade I have done (including to 16.04.1 LTS) uses this folder.

Comment: Sadly, when looking for references on this, I discovered that this question is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/130969/can-i-look-at-the-upgrade-log-after-a-distribution-upgrade

Comment: That reference does not provide an answer for this case, as the directory being mentioned is empty.